# Creating onclick image overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, overlay

**What I have**: I currently have code so where if you hover over an image, the overlay will slide from bottom to top.

**What I want**: I want to be able to achieve the same overlay slide from bottom to top with onclick instead of hover. I'm having trouble figuring out how to achieve this.

Code:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Slide in Overlay from the Bottom</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your javaScript code? Where is the click action??

Comment: you will need to add JS code, by setting `on click` to add/delete style of the div

Comment: `onclick` will require JavaScript; have you tried anything yet? By only CSS, you could possibly achieve something using `a:visited`, but it would likely not work as desired.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary -- there isn't any JavaScript. The hover is currently done with CSS.

Comment: You need JavaScript/jQuery to attach and execute an action like click.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Know that! My intention was to tell the OP to use javaScript to make it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MMM

Slightly improvised Way

CSS

```
.container .overlay.show{
  height:100%;
}
```

JS

```
$(".container").on('click',function(){
    $(this).children(".overlay").toggleClass("show");
});
```

What this does is. on click it opens overlay, again on click it hides overlay

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Try this Javascript using jQuery

JS

```
$(".container").on('click',function(){
    $(this).children(".overlay").css("height","100%");
});
```

hope this helps..

Comment: @ehsan What are you going on about?

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you will need JavaScript, or better yet, jQuery. With jQuery, you can easily just apply the overlay to the children of `.container`:

```js
$(".container").on('click', function() {
  $(this).children(".overlay").css('height', '100%');
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Slide in Overlay from the Bottom</h2>
<p>Click on the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hey Obsidian, this helped a lot! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS alone.

I am able to achieve this by adding a `:focus` selector to match your `:hover` selector.

If your device supports `:hover` it will show on hover and **not require you to click**. If your device does not support `:hover` then clicking the element - on a touchscreen for example - will trigger the `:focus` state which in this case will *simulate* the effects of the `:hover` state.

In other words we change:

```
.container:hover .overlay
```

to

```
.container:hover .overlay, .container:focus .overlay
```

Read more about focus and it's usage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

**Working example:**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay, .container:focus .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Slide in Overlay from the Bottom</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ChandraShekhar you can use Chrome dev tools to simulate touchscreens. If the div is clicked on a touchscreen it triggers the :focus state and displays whatever effect you have that shows up on :hover.

Comment: but iam not getting it on click why ??

Comment: @ChandraShekhar Make sure you have [mobile mode](https://image.ibb.co/kFg0ja/Capture.png) on or use a mobile device to view the snippet. If your device supports :hover it will show on hover and not require you to click. If your device does not support :hover then clicking the element will trigger the :focus state which in this case will simulate the effects of the OP's :hover state.

Answer (score 1):

**Css:**

```
.fullHeight {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container').click(function(){
        $('.overlay',this).addClass('fullHeight');
    })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container').click(function(){
        $('.overlay',this).addClass('fullHeight');
    })
})
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.fullHeight {
    height: 100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Slide in Overlay from the Bottom</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>
<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple images on your webpage you can use this snippet I created for my own project, all it does is to check if the element returns true on hover or null if it does not.

```
function isHover(e) {
    return (e.parentElement.querySelector(':hover') === e);
}
var myDiv = document.getElementById('container');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function checkHover() {
    var hovered = isHover(myDiv);
    if (hovered !== checkHover.hovered) {
        hovered ? document.getElementById("overlay").style = "width: 100%;" : document.getElementById(
                "overlay").style =
            "";
    }
});
```